# Image in one section of website takes up the entire page

Tags: html, css

I am redesigning a website for fun and I was messing around with some JQuery and some CSS effects. When you click on an arrow, everything on the page gets pushed down and a video comes up. The issues is I'm trying to create a section for an image. However, changing the background-size of the image to cover ends up making the entire image take up the screen. If I manually change the size of the image then the image is distorted.

Here is the HTML:

```
<section id="content">
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dvrqqa6ja/image/upload/v1466799500/background_image_mjh10z.jpg"class="stuff"> </img> 
  <h1>Click the arrow to view Kai Greene's Scar Story</h1>
 <span class="msg"><button = class="btn btn-danger">Sign up for our News Letter</button></span>

</section>
<article class="buy">
  <h1 class="products text-center">View other products</h1>
</article>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.stuff{
  margin-top: 100px; 
  background-soze: cover; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    z-index: 0; 
}
```

You can view the entire code on codepen: http://codepen.io/sibraza/pen/wWgqBO

Comment: `background-soze`? Try on checking the spelling. Also you can use `width` or `height` for the image size. No `background-size` needed. You can use `object-fit: cover` to keep image aspect ratio whatever the width or height you set.

Comment: You are adding that class to an image - this really doesn't make sense / doesn't make it a background image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `background-size`, use `width` or `height` to set your desired image size. You can also use `object-fit: cover` to keep the image aspect ratio no matter what size you set. Its like doing a "cropping" effect.

Comment: @Codes316
You're welcome mate. I would appreciate it too if you upvote my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to change the size of the image manually. Setting the width to a certain value and setting height to auto or visa versa should not distort the image. So setting either width or height to auto shouldn't distort the image.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp is a helpful resource for image sizing in CSS